# joining two dataset to get optimal result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task, snowsql

Thanks in advance! this is little long question but hopefully it is clear and concise.

I have two different query bringing two data sets.

both datasets are bringing data in same grain for similar area.

**first data set has multiple snapshots per month of a season , so it have three different metrics value for each season for same grain for a season.**

Dataset 1 ( country , season , month , metric is column names )
(1. A , autumn, 9/1, 1  is the record for column)

**country**       **season**     **month**        **metric**

1. A,              autumn ,     9/1 ,   1
2. A,              autumn ,     10/1 ,   2
3. A,              autumn ,     11/1 ,  3

**where as the second data set has one snapshots (just one month out of season) for a season, so it will have just one snapshot per season.**

Dataset 2

**country**            **season**         **month**            **metric**

1. A ,                    autumn ,           9/1   ,                4

**my current approach  of full outer join is giving me the following output**

**country**                **season**       **month**       **metric1**      **metric2**

1. A,                     autumn,            9/1,               1,             4
2. A,                     autumn,            10/1,              2,
3. A,                     autumn ,           11/1,              3 ,

****Notice the metric2 for 10/1 and 11/1 are blank or zero if use nvl but what we need is to populate
same value 4 for these two months as well** **how can we achieve this**

**or FINAL OUTPUT should look something like this**

**country**                **season**       **month**       **metric1**      **metric2**

1. A,                     autumn,            9/1,               1,             4
2. A,                     autumn,            10/1,              2,             4
3. A,                     autumn ,           11/1,              3 ,            4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Snowflake at all but assuming it uses fairly standard SQL, this should be as simple as:

```
SELECT a.country, a.season, a.month, a.metric AS metric1, b.metric AS metric2
FROM dataset1 a
INNER JOIN dataset2 b
ON a.country = b.country AND a.season = b.season
```

i.e. It shouldn't need a full outer join and should need to match only on country and season.
P.S. It would help if you showed the SQL you've tried as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change the join condition.

Instead of just using

```
Dataset1.country = Dataset2.country 
and Dataset1.month = Dataset2.month
```

Use the conditions in join as -

```
Dataset1.country = Dataset2.country 
and Dataset1.month >= Dataset2.month
```

Now I don’t know about the data type of month. I have put the logic but to actually compare you may need to do type casting as required for proper comparison using >=

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` and a window function.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT d1.country, d1.season, d1.month, d1.metric AS metric1,
       COALESCE(d2.metric,
                LAG(d2.metric IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY d1.country ORDER BY d1.month)
               ) AS metric2
FROM dataset1 d1 LEFT JOIN
     dataset2 d2
     ON d2.country = d1.country AND d2.season = d1.season;
```

You don't specify the exact logic for imputing the value, so this takes the most recent non-`NULL` value.